# expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment ERROR

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim cntrl As ComboBox = DirectCast(cboorlstCntrl, ComboBox)
Dim adors As New ADODB.Recordset


cntrl.Items.Add(adors.Fields(1))  
cntrl.Items.Add(cntrl.SelectedIndex) = adors.Fields(0)
```

in the vb.net code above,Last  line shows the error.Please solve it

Comment: You cannot use the `=` operator here. The parameter of `.Add()` is what you add in the ComboBox. If you want to add an item at a specific index you'd do: `cntrl.Items.Insert(cntrl.SelectedIndex, adors.Fields(0))`. **See:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.insert(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VisualVincent I'd put that down as the answer

Comment: @DavidWilson Okay. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Add()` method is a sub, it is no object and it doesn't return any object either. This means that it cannot be assigned to anything (which is one of the things the equal (`=`) operator does).

`Add()` takes only one parameter, which is what to add to the ComboBox's items. So if you want to add anything to a specific index you'd use the `Insert()` method instead:

```
cntrl.Items.Insert(cntrl.SelectedIndex, adors.Fields(0))
```

---

For more info, see: [Insert Method (Int32, Object) - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.insert(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)